# how to registration using openid in apche super set

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

***strong text***[enter link description here][1][enter image description here][1]i am trying to openid registration from apache superset and flask app builder showing like this error message
**```
Not possible to register you at the moment, try again later;

```
how to registration using openid  in apche super set or Flask app builder AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID 



[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv86m.png)

i want to registration and login using apache superset or flas app builder 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYwc.png

[screenshot link][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYwc.png
```